# Convert Nested JSON to CSV in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have following JSON, which I would like to convert into CSV.

Elements of JSON are going to be constant, if value is not present, then it will be null. But attribute will still be available.

I want to convert it into CSV with 9 columns.

I have flow like this =>

```
InvokeHTTP->EvaluateJSONPath->InferAvroSchema-> UpdateAttribute->ConvertRecord
```

last processor is failing.

`a,b,c,d,e,sub-a,sub-b,sub-c,sub-d`

```
[
  {
    "a": "a-value",
    "b": "b-value",
    "c": "c-value",
    "d": "d-value",
    "e": 123,
    "sub_value": {
      "sub-a": "sub-a-value",
      "sub-b": null,
      "sub-c": "sub-c-value",
      "sub-d": "sub-d-value"
    }
  },
  {
    "a": "a2-value",
    "b": "b2-value",
    "c": "c2-value",
    "d": "d2-value",
    "e": 123,
    "sub_value": {
      "sub-a": "sub-2a-value",
      "sub-b": "sub-2a-value",
      "sub-c": "sub-2c-value",
      "sub-d": "sub-2d-value"
    }
  }
]
```

### Update 2

What if, I do not want to use attributes in JsonReader? (i may have too many values, and it may become maintenance nightmare). is thr some other way?

Can I still solve my usecase by using avroschema while reading and writing?

input-json =>

```
{"store_number":"33152","store_name":"33152 WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374","store_display_name":"WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374","store_type_name":"Off Trade","street":"CALLE MORELOS 2019, JARDINES DEL COUNTRY, EL PERUL 2DA SECC.","city":"SALAMANCA","postal_code":"36764","latitude":20.665996,"longitude":-101.232345,"is_active":true,"manager_name":"MITZI ORTIZ","is_deleted":false,"manager_phone":null,"manager_email":null,"region_name":"A III","district_name":null,"branch_name":null,"retailer_name":"WALMART DE MEXICO","state_code":null,"store_additional_attributes":{"additional_attribute_1":"SSS MAINSTREAM","additional_attribute_2":"MAINSTREAM","additional_attribute_3":"PROM.SEM.53","additional_attribute_4":"SSS","additional_attribute_5":"R G","additional_attribute_6":"R.G@diageo.com","additional_attribute_11":"XEL HA MASTACHE","additional_attribute_12":"CALDERON VANESSA"}}
```

avro-schema-text (for JsonTreeReader)=>

```
{"type":"record","name":"jsn_to_csv","fields":[{"name":"store_number","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"1001\"'"},{"name":"store_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"1001 BODEGA AURRERA CHIMALHUACAN 3762\"'"},{"name":"store_display_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"BODEGA AURRERA CHIMALHUACAN 3762\"'"},{"name":"store_type_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"Off Trade\"'"},{"name":"street","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"AV CHIMALHUACAN 428 COL: BENITO JUAREZ\"'"},{"name":"city","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"NEZAHUALCOYOTL\"'"},{"name":"postal_code","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"57000\"'"},{"name":"latitude","type":["double","null","int"],"doc":"Type inferred from '19.403'"},{"name":"longitude","type":["double","null","int"],"doc":"Type inferred from '-99.0078'"},{"name":"is_active","type":"boolean","doc":"Type inferred from 'true'"},{"name":"manager_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"GIOVANI GARCIA\"'"},{"name":"is_deleted","type":"boolean","doc":"Type inferred from 'false'"},{"name":"manager_phone","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"manager_email","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"region_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"A IV\"'"},{"name":"district_name","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"branch_name","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"retailer_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"WALMART DE MEXICO\"'"},{"name":"state_code","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"store_additional_attributes","type":{"type":"record","name":"store_additional_attributes","fields":[{"name":"additional_attribute_1","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SSS EMC\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_2","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"EMC\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_3","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"PROM.SEM.259\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_4","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SSS\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_5","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"FRANCISCO HERNANDEZ\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_6","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"a@a.com\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_11","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"GIOVANI GARCIA\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_12","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SOLIS MARCIAL ALAN\"'","default":null}]}}]}
```

JsonTreeReader

[image]

CSVRecordSetWriter - Avro Schema

`{"type":"record","name":"jsn_to_csv","fields":[{"name":"store_number","type":"string"},{"name":"store_name","type":"string"},{"name":"store_display_name","type":"string"},{"name":"additional_attribute_1","default":null,"type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]}]}`

CSVRecordSetWriter
[image]

output=>

```
store_number,store_name,store_display_name,additional_attribute_1
33152,33152 WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374,WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374,
```

last column value is blank, it seems. how can I give reference of nested JSON attribute while writing it?

Template code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><template encoding-version="1.2"><description></description><groupId>e67d1c1e-38c8-1085-8460-d34d1eab4f96</groupId><name>DNU_r_writer</name><snippet><connections><id>a554ad4c-5255-38a8-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7ad8214e-4359-3339-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>89b6d4b6-6c38-34f5-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>350019df-a89c-3065-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>ac868965-be33-3190-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>success</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7ad8214e-4359-3339-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><connections><id>51283208-4111-3683-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><backPressureDataSizeThreshold>1 GB</backPressureDataSizeThreshold><backPressureObjectThreshold>10000</backPressureObjectThreshold><destination><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>9060f008-2053-3dc0-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></destination><flowFileExpiration>0 sec</flowFileExpiration><labelIndex>1</labelIndex><name></name><selectedRelationships>failure</selectedRelationships><source><groupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</groupId><id>7ad8214e-4359-3339-0000-000000000000</id><type>PROCESSOR</type></source><zIndex>0</zIndex></connections><controllerServices><id>2b600734-09f6-3b38-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><bundle><artifact>nifi-record-serialization-services-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><comments></comments><descriptors><entry><key>Schema Write Strategy</key><value><name>Schema Write Strategy</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-access-strategy</key><value><name>schema-access-strategy</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-registry</key><value><identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.schemaregistry.services.SchemaRegistry</identifiesControllerService><name>schema-registry</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-name</key><value><name>schema-name</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-version</key><value><name>schema-version</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-branch</key><value><name>schema-branch</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-text</key><value><name>schema-text</name></value></entry><entry><key>Date Format</key><value><name>Date Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Time Format</key><value><name>Time Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Timestamp Format</key><value><name>Timestamp Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>CSV Format</key><value><name>CSV Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Value Separator</key><value><name>Value Separator</name></value></entry><entry><key>Include Header Line</key><value><name>Include Header Line</name></value></entry><entry><key>Quote Character</key><value><name>Quote Character</name></value></entry><entry><key>Escape Character</key><value><name>Escape Character</name></value></entry><entry><key>Comment Marker</key><value><name>Comment Marker</name></value></entry><entry><key>Null String</key><value><name>Null String</name></value></entry><entry><key>Trim Fields</key><value><name>Trim Fields</name></value></entry><entry><key>Quote Mode</key><value><name>Quote Mode</name></value></entry><entry><key>Record Separator</key><value><name>Record Separator</name></value></entry><entry><key>Include Trailing Delimiter</key><value><name>Include Trailing Delimiter</name></value></entry><entry><key>csvutils-character-set</key><value><name>csvutils-character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><name>CSVRecordSetWriter</name><persistsState>false</persistsState><properties><entry><key>Schema Write Strategy</key><value>no-schema</value></entry><entry><key>schema-access-strategy</key><value>schema-text-property</value></entry><entry><key>schema-registry</key></entry><entry><key>schema-name</key><value>jsn_to_csv</value></entry><entry><key>schema-version</key><value>${avro.schema}</value></entry><entry><key>schema-branch</key></entry><entry><key>schema-text</key><value>{"type":"record","name":"jsn_to_csv","fields":[{"name":"store_number","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"33152\"'"},{"name":"store_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"33152 WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374\"'"},{"name":"store_display_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374\"'"},{"name":"additional_attribute_1","default":null,"type":[{"type":"null"},{"type":"string"}]}]}</value></entry><entry><key>Date Format</key></entry><entry><key>Time Format</key></entry><entry><key>Timestamp Format</key></entry><entry><key>CSV Format</key></entry><entry><key>Value Separator</key></entry><entry><key>Include Header Line</key></entry><entry><key>Quote Character</key></entry><entry><key>Escape Character</key></entry><entry><key>Comment Marker</key></entry><entry><key>Null String</key></entry><entry><key>Trim Fields</key></entry><entry><key>Quote Mode</key></entry><entry><key>Record Separator</key></entry><entry><key>Include Trailing Delimiter</key></entry><entry><key>csvutils-character-set</key></entry></properties><state>DISABLED</state><type>org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVRecordSetWriter</type></controllerServices><controllerServices><id>50827b89-5d05-3339-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><bundle><artifact>nifi-record-serialization-services-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><comments></comments><descriptors><entry><key>schema-access-strategy</key><value><name>schema-access-strategy</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-registry</key><value><identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.schemaregistry.services.SchemaRegistry</identifiesControllerService><name>schema-registry</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-name</key><value><name>schema-name</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-version</key><value><name>schema-version</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-branch</key><value><name>schema-branch</name></value></entry><entry><key>schema-text</key><value><name>schema-text</name></value></entry><entry><key>Date Format</key><value><name>Date Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Time Format</key><value><name>Time Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Timestamp Format</key><value><name>Timestamp Format</name></value></entry></descriptors><name>JsonTreeReader</name><persistsState>false</persistsState><properties><entry><key>schema-access-strategy</key><value>schema-text-property</value></entry><entry><key>schema-registry</key></entry><entry><key>schema-name</key></entry><entry><key>schema-version</key></entry><entry><key>schema-branch</key></entry><entry><key>schema-text</key><value>{"type":"record","name":"jsn_to_csv","fields":[{"name":"store_number","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"1001\"'"},{"name":"store_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"1001 BODEGA AURRERA CHIMALHUACAN 3762\"'"},{"name":"store_display_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"BODEGA AURRERA CHIMALHUACAN 3762\"'"},{"name":"store_type_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"Off Trade\"'"},{"name":"street","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"AV CHIMALHUACAN 428 COL: BENITO JUAREZ\"'"},{"name":"city","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"NEZAHUALCOYOTL\"'"},{"name":"postal_code","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"57000\"'"},{"name":"latitude","type":["double","null","int"],"doc":"Type inferred from '19.403'"},{"name":"longitude","type":["double","null","int"],"doc":"Type inferred from '-99.0078'"},{"name":"is_active","type":"boolean","doc":"Type inferred from 'true'"},{"name":"manager_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"GIOVANI GARCIA\"'"},{"name":"is_deleted","type":"boolean","doc":"Type inferred from 'false'"},{"name":"manager_phone","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"manager_email","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"region_name","type":"string","doc":"Type inferred from '\"A IV\"'"},{"name":"district_name","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"branch_name","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"retailer_name","type":["string","null"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"WALMART DE MEXICO\"'"},{"name":"state_code","type":"null","doc":"Type inferred from 'null'"},{"name":"store_additional_attributes","type":{"type":"record","name":"store_additional_attributes","fields":[{"name":"additional_attribute_1","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SSS EMC\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_2","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"EMC\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_3","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"PROM.SEM.259\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_4","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SSS\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_5","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"FRANCISCO HERNANDEZ\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_6","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"a@a.com\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_11","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"GIOVANI GARCIA\"'","default":null},{"name":"additional_attribute_12","type":["null","string"],"doc":"Type inferred from '\"SOLIS MARCIAL ALAN\"'","default":null}]}}]}</value></entry><entry><key>Date Format</key></entry><entry><key>Time Format</key></entry><entry><key>Timestamp Format</key></entry></properties><state>ENABLED</state><type>org.apache.nifi.json.JsonTreeReader</type></controllerServices><processors><id>89b6d4b6-6c38-34f5-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>640.8075097656251</x><y>217.50194427490328</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>File Size</key><value><name>File Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value><name>Batch Size</name></value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value><name>Data Format</name></value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value><name>Unique FlowFiles</name></value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key><value><name>generate-ff-custom-text</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>File Size</key><value>0B</value></entry><entry><key>Batch Size</key><value>1</value></entry><entry><key>Data Format</key><value>Text</value></entry><entry><key>Unique FlowFiles</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>generate-ff-custom-text</key><value>{"store_number":"33152","store_name":"33152 WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374","store_display_name":"WALMART JARDINES DEL COUNTRY 2374","store_type_name":"Off Trade","street":"CALLE MORELOS 2019, JARDINES DEL COUNTRY, EL PERUL 2DA SECC.","city":"SALAMANCA","postal_code":"36764","latitude":20.665996,"longitude":-101.232345,"is_active":true,"manager_name":"MITZI ORTIZ","is_deleted":false,"manager_phone":null,"manager_email":null,"region_name":"A III","district_name":null,"branch_name":null,"retailer_name":"WALMART DE MEXICO","state_code":null,"store_additional_attributes":{"additional_attribute_1":"SSS MAINSTREAM","additional_attribute_2":"MAINSTREAM","additional_attribute_3":"PROM.SEM.53","additional_attribute_4":"SSS","additional_attribute_5":"R G","additional_attribute_6":"R.G@diageo.com","additional_attribute_11":"XEL HA MASTACHE","additional_attribute_12":"CALDERON VANESSA"}}</value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>1d</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>GenerateFlowFile</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile</type></processors><processors><id>9060f008-2053-3dc0-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>0.0</x><y>0.0</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Log Level</key><value><name>Log Level</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value><name>Log Payload</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key><value><name>Attributes to Log</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-log-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key><value><name>Attributes to Ignore</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-ignore-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key><value><name>Log prefix</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Log Level</key><value>info</value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value>.*</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>LogAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>ac868965-be33-3190-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>542.0735742187499</x><y>5.220422363281159</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>Log Level</key><value><name>Log Level</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value><name>Log Payload</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key><value><name>Attributes to Log</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-log-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key><value><name>Attributes to Ignore</name></value></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key><value><name>attributes-to-ignore-regex</name></value></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key><value><name>Log prefix</name></value></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value><name>character-set</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>Log Level</key><value>info</value></entry><entry><key>Log Payload</key><value>false</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Log</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-log-regex</key><value>.*</value></entry><entry><key>Attributes to Ignore</key></entry><entry><key>attributes-to-ignore-regex</key></entry><entry><key>Log prefix</key></entry><entry><key>character-set</key><value>UTF-8</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>LogAttribute</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogAttribute</type></processors><processors><id>7ad8214e-4359-3339-0000-000000000000</id><parentGroupId>50098679-9a85-3379-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId><position><x>208.0796655273441</x><y>260.6401416015624</y></position><bundle><artifact>nifi-standard-nar</artifact><group>org.apache.nifi</group><version>1.6.0</version></bundle><config><bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel><comments></comments><concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount><descriptors><entry><key>record-reader</key><value><identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordReaderFactory</identifiesControllerService><name>record-reader</name></value></entry><entry><key>record-writer</key><value><identifiesControllerService>org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordSetWriterFactory</identifiesControllerService><name>record-writer</name></value></entry></descriptors><executionNode>ALL</executionNode><lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant><penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration><properties><entry><key>record-reader</key><value>50827b89-5d05-3339-0000-000000000000</value></entry><entry><key>record-writer</key><value>2b600734-09f6-3b38-0000-000000000000</value></entry></properties><runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis><schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod><schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy><yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration></config><name>ConvertRecord</name><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>failure</name></relationships><relationships><autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate><name>success</name></relationships><state>STOPPED</state><style/><type>org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord</type></processors></snippet><timestamp>10/08/2018 06:01:02 UTC</timestamp></template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **ConvertRecord** processor with

- JsonPathReader as Record Reader
- CsvSetWriter as Record Writer

***JsonPathReader Configs:***

As you are having static elements in the json so add new properties matching with the json path for all keys of the json message
[image]

***AvroSchemaRegistry Configs:***

This schema needs to match with the properties that we have added in JsonPathReader controller service.
[image]

***CsvSetWriter Configs:***

[image]

***Input:***

```
[
  {
    "a": "a-value",
    "b": "b-value",
    "c": "c-value",
    "d": "d-value",
    "e": 123,
    "sub_value": {
      "sub-a": "sub-a-value",
      "sub-b": null,
      "sub-c": "sub-c-value",
      "sub-d": "sub-d-value"
    }
  },
  {
    "a": "a2-value",
    "b": "b2-value",
    "c": "c2-value",
    "d": "d2-value",
    "e": 123,
    "sub_value": {
      "sub-a": "sub-2a-value",
      "sub-b": "sub-2a-value",
      "sub-c": "sub-2c-value",
      "sub-d": "sub-2d-value"
    }
  }
]
```

***Output:***

```
a,b,c,d,e,sub-a,sub-b,sub-c,sub-d
a-value,b-value,c-value,d-value,123,sub-a-value,,sub-c-value,sub-d-value
a2-value,b2-value,c2-value,d2-value,123,sub-2a-value,sub-2a-value,sub-2c-value,sub-2d-value
```

For template that i tried will be found in [this](https://github.com/shureddy/Templates/blob/Dynamic_convertion_from_json_to_csv/JsonPathReader.xml) link.

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, i don't think we can give reference a nested key using avro schema, This is only possible by using **UpdateRecord (or) JsonPathReader controller services** and adding new properties that refers the nested path(as i mentioned in the answer above). To flatten the json you can use **FlattenRecord** processor then use UpdateRecord processor to swap the values to refer your desired name. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html

Comment: yes, to keep avro-schema dynamic, i did FlattenJson -> InferAvroSchema -> RecordConver -> SplitRecord -> Replace text (literal) -> merger content (defragmented, to keep header on top).  

 One change I had to do with FlattenJson, I avoided using '.' as a seperator, as avro doesnt play well with anything other than '_'. And in my case key already had '_', so i used 'C' (as all my header was in smaller case). but then reverted it back to at the end.

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, Great, Awesome job you did :), Thanks for letting us know about the **issues and resolutions**..!!